# Callback function does not run until submit is clicked twice

Tags: reactjs, form-submit, onsubmit

The onSubmit callback paymentHandler is supposed to run as soon as the form is submitted, I didn't specify button type. but as soon as I click submit button, nothing happens until I click the submit button again. The button and form inputs are styled components. They work fine in other pages.

```
  const callPaystack = () => {
    fetch('https://api.paystack.co/transaction/initialize', {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
       'Authorization': `Bearer ${import.meta.env.VITE_PAYSTACK_SECRET_KEY}`,
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     },
     body: JSON.stringify({
       email: buyerEmail, 
       amount: totalPrice * 100,
       channels: ["card", "bank", "qr", "ussd"],
       metadata: {
         "cancel_action": "https://crown-storex.netlify.app",
       }
     }),
    }).then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      setPaymentResult(data);
      console.log(paymentResult)
    })
  }

  const paymentHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await callPaystack();
    location.href = paymentResult.data.authorization_url;
  
  }

      <form onSubmit={paymentHandler}>
        <FormInput
          label="Email"
          name="email"
          type="email"
          value={buyerEmail}
          onChange={(e) => setBuyerData({ ...buyerData, buyerEmail: e.target.value })}
          required
        />
        <Button  buttonType={buyerEmail ? "inverted" : "disabled"} >Pay Now With Paystack</Button>
      </form>
```

Comment: Could you add the markup/jsx for the submit button as well?

Comment: I pasted the form itself including the button

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning the result from the `fetch` your async function. To give a simplified example, what you do is similar like this:

```js
const foo = async function () {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(response => response.json()).then(json => console.log(json));
}

const paymentHandler = async () => {
  await foo();
  console.log('this should be at the end, right?');
}

paymentHandler();
```

What you should be doing is something like this:

```js
const foo = async function () {
  return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then(response => response.json())
}

const paymentHandler = async () => {
  const result = await foo();
  console.log(result);
  console.log('this should be at the end, right?');
}

paymentHandler();
```

So what happens in the second example, is you return the promise from the fetch function, inside the first example you return a promise (async function always return promise) that is not part of your fetch function, and therefore resolves immediately. So my advice is: return the result from `fetch` and then change the URL.

NB: One more thing you might try if you don't want to rewrite your function is use a `useEffect` hook that is part of React, and set `paymentResult` as a depencency. This means whenever `paymentResult` changes this function runs. Something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (paymentResult.status === 'success') {
    location.href = paymentResult.data.authorization_url;
  }
}, [paymentResult])
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation the other way worked.

Answer (score 1):

This should be happening because you are updating the state which updates after paymenthandler is completed entirely.

You should return the value from paymenthandler and use to set location.href

```
const paymentHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
   let val = await callPaystack();
    location.href = val.data.authorization_url;
  
  }
```